# Can someone please explain why the same logic of a query seems to be working in ORACLE but not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The original question:

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.(source hackerrank)

name of the table: Station; the name of required attribute: city

My query when I use MYSQL:

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where lower(city) regexp "^[^aeiou]*" 
or lower(city) regexp "[^aeiou]$";
```

I get names like 'Aguanga' and 'East Irvine' in my output on **MySQL** BUT when I use **oracle** and write the same logic in that, I get the correct output. The query I wrote for Oracle:

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where regexp_like(lower(city), '^[^aeiou]') 
or regexp_like(lower(city),'[^aeiou]$');
```

I am new at SQL and do not understand why this is not working. I've used this method to get the correct output in MySQL for not starting with a vowel and not ending with a vowel but for 2 different questions separately.

Comment: Yes, they are NOT the same database

Comment: The regular expressions you posted are not the same either. You have a `*` in the first one that's not in the others.

Comment: Just to be clear in all but he simplest of queries code is not transportable between dialects.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I'm really dumb. Removing the * and it works. Thank you ! I feel bad for wasting 20 mins on this. @Aioros